# haskell tree using fold operation

Tags: haskell, tree, fold

How would I go about writing a **contains**, **balanced** function given this definition using folds.

```
data Tree a = Tree a [Tree a]

treeFold :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
treeContains :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
treeBalanced :: Tree a -> Bool
```

**Note that in the above definition, empty trees are not allowed, and that a leaf is a tree with an empty list of subtrees.**

A **contains** function determines whether the tree contains a given label.

A **balanced** function determine whether a tree is balanced.

A tree is balanced if the heights of its subtrees diﬀerent by at most one, and the subtrees are balanced

The contains function that I have got so far is given below.

```
treeContains :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool
treeContains a = treeFold (\x y -> if a == x then True else ...)
```

So how do you do the else part indicate by ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at functions `and`, `or` and `any` in the prelude. Especially figure out what type of an term you should write in place of `...`

Answer (score 5):

As you are learning, [I shall answer your question by asking you more questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_questioning).

---

Re `treeContains`:

1. What value do you want to compute in the `...`? What should it mean? What is its type?

   > In the `...`, you want to look for the next node in the tree and check if that node is what you are after.

   1. Which node is the next node? If the current node has four subtrees, why would we
      want to check only one of them? What if there are no subtrees?

      > Check if the node that you are after is in the root. If it is return true otherwise check if it is in any of the sub trees. If it is return true otherwise check if there are any sub sub trees. If there are then check the node in those sub sub tree otherwise return false.

      1. You are saying you should check the nodes in [breadth-first order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Is that the best order to check them in? What other orders might you check them? Might they be easier?
2. What does `y` mean? What is its type?

   > `y` is the list containing elements of type `b`.

   1. Can you be more specific? (I am asking in the specific context of `treeContains`,
      not the more general context of `treeFold`.) What is `b`?

      > `y` is a list containing elements of type `Tree a` (so `b` is `Tree a`)

      Are you sure?

      1. You have been told that `treeContains :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Bool`, so what
         is the type of `treeContains a`?
      2. You have decided that `treeContains a = treeFold (\x y -> if a == x then True else ...)`. Given that and your answer to the previous question, what is the type of `treeFold (\x y -> if a == x then True else ...)`?
      3. Given your answer to the previous question, and given that
         `treeFold :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b`, what is the type of
         `(\x y -> if a == x then True else ...)`?
      4. Given your answer to the previous question, what is the type of `y`?
   2. What does this value mean? Does it tell you something about other nodes in the tree?
      Entire subtrees? Which ones? What does it tell you about them? Their size? Their
      height? Whether they're balanced? Something about their contents?
3. Could you compute the `...` from `y`? What function(s) would you need? What would it/their type(s) be?

---

Re `treeBalanced`:

1. If you wanted to write a function `treeHeight :: Tree a -> Int`, how would you do that? Would you use `treeFold`?
2. If you wanted to write a function `treeHeightAndBalanced :: Tree a -> (Int, Bool)`, how would you do that?
3. If you already had `treeHeightAndBalanced :: Tree a -> (Int, Bool)`, how could you write `treeBalanced :: Tree a -> Bool`?

Comment: treeContains  
  
In the ...,  you want to look for the next node in the tree and check if that node is what you are after. y is the list containing elements of type b.

Comment: Check if the node that you are after is in the root. If it is return true otherwise check if it is in any of the sub trees. If it is return true otherwise check if there are any sub sub trees. If there are then check the node in those sub sub tree otherwise return false. y is a list containing elements of type Tree a

Comment: @Ishan See extra questions I have edited in. You should probably work through the questions under 2.1 first, then answer 2.2, then revisit 1.1.

Comment: The `treeContains` takes an a and the Tree of type Tree a and returns a Boolean. The type of treeContains is `a -> Tree a -> Bool`. The `treeFold` function takes a function of type `(a -> [b] -> b)` and a tree of type Tree a and returns a result by recursively applying the fold operation to the subtrees, then applying the function to the label at the root and the results returned from the subtrees. The type of the tree fold operation is `(a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b`.

Comment: The type of `(\x y -> if a == x then True else ...)` is `(a -> [b] -> b)` and the type of x is `a`, y is `[b]` and the type of `if a == x then True else ..`. is `b`. The y value tells you the number of nodes in the subtree.

Comment: @Ishan Given that `treeContains a = treeFold (\x y -> if a == x then True else ...)`, shouldn't `treeContains a` and `treeFold (\x y -> if a == x then True else ...)` have the same types? Would you like to reconsider your answers?

Comment: yes they should. So type of `treeFold (\x y -> if a == x then True else ...)` should be Bool

Comment: @Ishan And therefore `y` has what type?